# How to create custom login with Vaadin4Spring MVP structure and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin, mvp, vaadin4spring

My current project is based on the structure of peholmst's vaadin4spring MVP:

https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/samples/mvp-sample

Im using **Vaadin 7.5.3**, **SpringBoot 1.2.5.RELEASE** and **JSR-330 1.0 (@Inject)**.

Now i want to create a new vaadin view login page in combination with spring security... My attempt was the following:

HttpSecurityConfigurer.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;

[...]

void configure(Environment env, ApplicationContext appContext, HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/VAADIN/**", "/PUSH/**", "/UIDL/**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
         .csrf().disable();


   http
         .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).permitAll()
             .and()
         .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
}

[...]
```

LoginUI.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

import my.example.application.ui.presenter.Action;
import my.example.application.ui.presenter.LoginPresenter;

@SpringUI(path = "/login")
@Theme("valo")
@Title("MyLogin")
public class MyLoginUI extends UI {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1746340376430847935L;

    @Inject
    LoginPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        eventBus.publish(this, Action.START);
        setContent(presenter.getView());
    }

}
```

LoginPresenter.java

```
import org.vaadin.spring.events.Event;
import org.vaadin.spring.events.EventScope;
import org.vaadin.spring.events.annotation.EventBusListenerMethod;
import org.vaadin.spring.navigator.Presenter;
import org.vaadin.spring.navigator.annotation.VaadinPresenter;

import my.example.application.ui.view.LoginView;

@VaadinPresenter(viewName = LoginView.NAME)
public class LoginPresenter extends Presenter<LoginView> {

    @EventBusListenerMethod(scope = EventScope.SESSION, filter = StartupFilter.class)
    public void onStartup(Event<Action> event) {
        getView().setBody();
    }

}
```

LoginView.java

```
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.UIScope;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringView;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
[...]

@UIScope
@SpringView(name = LoginView.NAME, ui = MyLoginUI.class)
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8034398112492147989L;

    public static final String NAME = "loginView";

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        setMargin(true);
        setSpacing(true);
        setSizeFull();
    }

    public void setBody() {
        addComponent(new Label("Heey, thats my login page! :)"));
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    }

}
```

So when i start the application my browser redirects to "http://localhost:8080/login" but its rendering only the vaadin loading animation:

[image: Vaadin loading animation]

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think that your spring security is still blocking some access to needed resources. Look in the webbrowser for the requests sent to the server and then answers received. There are probably some with 401 or 301 response codes

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked at the network section in firebug but there are only 200's and 2x 302... The first 302 is a GET on http://localhost:8080/ and the second one is a POST on http://localhost:8080/login?v-1440155741588...

Comment: Clear the Cache before looking AT firebug...

Comment: I did it, but there are no changes...

Comment: On Serverside in the logs also the same?

Comment: Yes, there are no details about it. I solved the problem temporary with the use of thymeleaf...

Comment: Look to this example: https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/samples/security-sample-shared  I implemented it and it's working succesfuly.

Comment: The problem is that Vaadin4Spring Security is kind of rudimentary... https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/extensions/security Either rememberMe function is not supported or Vaadin Push mode is not supported... I want both of them :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it took ages to figure out a workaround:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // Authentication is not needed for the login page
        // Permit access to VAADIN resources explicitly
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/vaadinServlet/**", "/login")
                .permitAll();
        // TODO: For some reason I need the "auth" URL parameter. W/o the VAADIN UI does not load
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login?auth");

        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

        // Any request needs to be authenticated. If a user is not authenticated => Login Page
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

Usually it should work without the **?auth** in the login page URL(it can be any URL extension).
Usually it should work when using **permitAll()** at the **loginPage()** method.
Usually it should work without explicitly allowing **/login**.

If anyone has an explanation for this I would appreciate that. I debugged spring and looked into the responses of the browser. Probably it's something in the *.js files that VAADIN creates for its widgets.

Comment: This solution sounds very strange but I will try it out!